# Why is the Extra white space above the drawer and appbar [flutter],

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

[image: enter image here]

Why there is an extra space above the drawer and appbar, it was working fine and all of a sudden it happened, I have tried checking all scaffolds, appbar and tried adding safearea to materialApp also and everything looks fine, I am also using screen utils package too.
This is my part of the code

> main

```
final SecureStorage secureStorage = Get.put(SecureStorage());
var localMemberid = Rxn<String>();
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SecureStorage.readLocalSecureData('memberid')
      .then((value) => localMemberid.value = value);

  runApp(
    ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: ScreenUtil.defaultSize,
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return GetMaterialApp(
          title: "Onyx",
          initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
          getPages: AppPages.routes,
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xFF0456E5, color)),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

> Settings page

```
class SettingView extends GetView<SettingController> {
  final bool isAppBar;
  const SettingView({Key? key, this.isAppBar = true}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: isAppBar
          ? AppBar(
              title: const Text('Setting'),
              centerTitle: true,
            )
          : null,
      drawer: const CDrawer(),
      body: Column(children: [
        CustomSizedBox(height: 35.0.h),
        const SettingTile(
            title: 'Change Email',
            icons: Icon(
              Icons.email_outlined,
            )),
        const SettingTile(
            title: 'Change Password',
            icons: Icon(
              Icons.key_outlined,
            )),
        const SettingTile(
            title: 'Change Language',
            icons: Icon(
              Icons.language_outlined,
            )),
        const SettingTile(
            title: 'Notification',
            icons: Icon(
              Icons.notifications_outlined,
            )),
        SettingTile(
          title: 'Log Out',
          icons: const Icon(Icons.logout_outlined),
          onTap: controller.onTapLogOut,
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

> CDrawer

```
class CDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const CDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: const Text('Mohammed Abid'),
            accountEmail: const Text('sample@gmail.com'),
            currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Image.asset('assets/person.png'),
              ),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: colorPrimary,
            ),
          ),

          ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
              title: const Text('My Package'),
              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.MY_PACKAGES)),
          ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
              title: const Text('Purchase Package'),
              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.PURCHASE_PACKAGE)),
          ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.app_registration),
              title: const Text('Book An Appointment'),
              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.BOOK_AN_APPOINTMENT)),
          ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.history),
              title: const Text('Order History'),
              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.ORDER_HISTORY)),
          ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.group),
              title: const Text('My Attendance'),
              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.MY_ATTENDANCE)),
          ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.schedule),
              title: const Text('My Schedule'),
              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.MY_SCHEDULE)),
          ListTile(
              title: const Text('Offer'),
              leading: const Icon(Icons.local_offer_outlined),
              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.OFFERS)),
          // ListTile(
          //   title: Text('Feed Back'),
          //   leading: Icon(Icons.feedback_outlined),
          //   onTap: () => null,
          // ),
          ListTile(
              title: const Text('Location'),
              leading: const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.LOCATION)),
          ListTile(
              title: const Text('Contact Us'),
              leading: const Icon(Icons.contact_phone_outlined),
              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.CONTACT_US)),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Settings'),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.settings_outlined),
            onTap: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.SETTING),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code causing this issue?

Comment: i facing this issue in entier app so which part to code you would like to see

Comment: A part of code which i can use to replicate the issue.

Comment: modified the question, u can check it